ASP.NET Identity without Identity.EntityFramework in an ASP.NET (on .NET 4.x) project
After reading tons of posts on the internet and on stackoverflow, I still have difficulties getting ASP.NET Identity v2 to work without the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework package.
I have my own data provider and access layers.
My User class is based on an int primary key and I just want to implement the minimum classes (Users and Roles) to make the project work and allow a user with email and password to access my ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.x) web application.
So the only libraries I want to use are OWIN and Microsoft.Identity.
My IDE is Visual Studio 2019 (most of the samples I read, are based on VS 2013).
The post that comes closest to what I'm looking for is the following. Does new ASP.NET MVC identity framework work without Entity Framework and SQL Server?.
I created an ASP.NET MVC project with individual accounts, then I removed Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework and now I want to connect it to my own dbContext (which can be an entity dbcontext).
Can someone help me? Is there a sample project which meets my needs and which works (connection to the dbcontext with)?
SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false); 

Thanks for reading

I would rather extend the Identity class to include your existing implementation method which is your user class.
